# GraphQL : Not Getting EF Related objects after implementing Types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, graphql

For background, I am following the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuN94qNwQmM .

As the code is too long I am putting that in git https://github.com/dikeshkumar135/CommandERGQL

Now, coming to the problem, when I am making request with this body

```
    query{
     platform{
       id,
       name,
       commands{
         howTo
       }
     }
    }
```

I am getting the data for platform with commands value as null and the below error:

```
{
  "message": "There was no argument with the name `platform` found on the field `commands`.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 5,
      "column": 5
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "platform",
    1,
    "commands"
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "fieldName": "commands",
    "argumentName": "platform"
  }
```

If I remove the type it's working fine, but if I add type then the problem occurs to get related objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded hotchocolate packages from 12.0.1 to 11.0.8 ad it worked. It was a suggestion to my comment in youtube.

Answer (score 7):

In HotChocolate v12, `DependecyInjection` included in the `ResolverWith` method assumes all parameters as an `Argument`. Except for below

> There are also specific arguments that will be automatically populated by Hot Chocolate when the resolver is executed. These include Dependency injection services, DataLoaders, state, or even context like a parent value.

[Documentation Source](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/fetching-data/resolvers#arguments)

Here is some example for the upgrade for the tutorial you are using

```
public IQueryable<Command> GetCommands(
    [Parent] Platform platform,
    [ScopedService] AppDbContext context)
{
    return context.Commands.Where(p => p.PlatformId == platform.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have goal to update data, you can omit to use EF and use, just for exmaple, [NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql_to_sql_database.aspx) to set up graphql schema (including relation between schema objects) via json-style definition. Setting db-connection quite easy and under the hood it's ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Type class

```
 public class MajorType : ObjectType<Major>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Major> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Description("Offer Degree from the university");
            descriptor.Field(p => p.MinCreditHours).Description("Minimum credit hours for the degree");
            descriptor.Field(p => p.SetUser).Ignore();
            descriptor.Field(p => p.SetDate).Ignore();
            descriptor.Field(p => p.IsDeleted).Ignore();
          
            descriptor.Field(p=>p.Courses)
                .UseDbContext<CatalogueDBContext>()
                .ResolveWith<Resolvers>(p=>p.GetCourse(default!,default!))
                .Description("Avialable coures for the specific major");
        }
        private class Resolvers 
        {
            public IQueryable<Courses> GetCourse([Parent] Major major, [ScopedService] CatalogueDBContext context)
            {
                return context.Courses.Where(c=>c.MajorId == major.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```